# Can I turn off the Airflow experimental API?

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to disable the airflow experimental API? I've searched through examples of airflow.cfg but didn't see anything there that would achieve it. Perhaps something can be done using [`auth_backend`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configurations-ref.html#api) but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Airflow 1.10.11, the experimental API denies all requests by default (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/9611)).

If you are running an older version of Airflow, you can set

```
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```